# Can certifying an application protect it from viruses that inject itself into the program?

Tags: security

I'm having troubles of Windows Defender telling me that I have viruses in my EXEs.
It's a ramnit type, the one that would hide itself in executables and html files.
Could certifying the app using the tool provided in Visual Studio installation prevent the virus from slipping in?
I've seen my installers in storage that is downloaded from various sources completely intact.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming itself

Comment: @NicoHaase Tell me, where am I suppose to ask these things?

Comment: What do you mean by "certifying"? Are yo talking about binary signing like "Authenticode" for Windows? When it comes to malicious binaries you have to understand where the infection takes place, by someone taking your app, manidiying it and republishing it somewhere else or may be even on your PC (e.g. malicious library)?

Comment: Hold on, I think this is not so great. Maybe I should have researched before asking.